# When does negative charge represent a pair of electrons?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution, electrophilic-substitution

Probably a stupid question but it has been bugging me for quite some time.

I was reading Clayden (organic chemistry textbook) and in it, the author gives an example of $\ce{OH-}$ and $\ce{BH4-}$ to tell that in $\ce{OH-}$ the - shows that it has lone pair of electrons whereas in $\ce{BH4-}$ , the - simply means that it has a negative charge on it. It has no lone pairs.

For simple molecules like this, I have no problem what the - is supposed to mean (by simply drawing Lewis structures). But when it comes to complex molecules, I have no idea what to do.

There's a similar problem with the positive charge as well. Sometimes, it means vacant orbital, and sometimes it just means a positive charge.

Comment: One negative charge always means one electron in excess with respect to electric neutrality, and not necessarily a pair of electrons. One positive charge always means one electron missing with respect to electric neutrality, and not necessarily a vacant orbital.

Comment: Well, cation or anion radical certainly exist, but are mostly found in MS, or as chemical curiosities. Pretty slim chance you're gonna get a bottle of a anion radical salt, but could happen.

Answer (score 4):

> [OP] When does negative charge represent a pair of electrons?

Never. The negative charge means that there is one electron in excess of protons. It refers to the entire species (sometimes even emphasized in brackets like for $\ce{BH4-}$ below), so it makes no statement about which atom that extra electron "belongs" to, or whether it is paired or unpaired, or part of a bond or not.

[image]

> [OP ...] in $\ce{OH-}$ the - shows that it has lone pair of electrons whereas in $\ce{BH4-}$ , the - simply means that it has a negative charge on it

That does not make sense as written (by the OP or by Clayden, I can't tell). You are using the same symbol, so how would you know which of these two things it means. It is correct to say that hydroxide ions have lone pairs (3 in the conventional Lewis structure depiction), and the borohydride anion has none. You can't tell from the negative sign, though.

> [OP] For simple molecules like this, I have no problem what the - is supposed to mean (by simply drawing Lewis structures). But when it comes to complex molecules, I have no idea what to do.

For complex molecules, it makes sense to learn about formal charges. If there is a formal charge of negative one on an oxygen atom, you expect three lone pairs and one bond (just like in the simple hydroxide ion). If there is a formal charge of positive one on an oxygen atom, you expect one lone pair and three bonds (just like in the simple hydronium ion). Finally, if there in no formal charge, you expert two lone pairs and two bonds (or a double bond).

#### Acids and their conjugative bases

If you start with a Brønsted–Lowry acid that is uncharged, and it loses one proton, you expect a conjugative base with a negative charge. You could say that the bond with hydrogen "turned into a lone pair", as the hydrogen ion does not carry any electrons. This is how you get from water (oxygen has two lone pairs and two bonds) to hydroxide (oxygen has three lone pairs, one bond and a formal charge of negative one).

$\ce{BH3}$ is a Lewis acid. It does not lose a proton, but instead can react with hydride ($\ce{H-}$) or a hydride donor. While $\ce{BH3}$ does not have an octet on boron in its Lewis structure, $\ce{BH4-}$ does (it has four single bonds).

#### Isoelectronic species

Sometimes, you can go from unfamiliar to familiar by looking at isoelectronic species. $\ce{BH4-}$ is isoelectronic to $\ce{CH4}$, which is not known for having lone pairs. $\ce{OH-}$ is isoelectronic to $\ce{HF}$ (although written in the different order), and you might know that the fluorine in the Lewis structure of $\ce{HF}$ has three lone pairs.

#### Indistinguishability

Often in organic chemistry, we pretend that we know which electron or electron pair does what. On the other hand, we can't label a single electron like we can for atoms (using isotopes), and electrons are indistinguishable in a molecule. So you can't "blame" an excess charge on a specific electron, and you can't really track an electron from reactant to product species, although we sometimes pretend we can.

Answer (score 1):

The negative sign is a matter of accounting electrostatic charges even for complex molecules. Count the *total* number of protons in a given molecule or a given species, and count the total number of electrons. If the number is equal, that chemical entity is electrically neutral, if it has an excess proton, it is positively charged, and if there is an excess electron, there is a negative charge.

Don't confuse these signs with formal charges and signs associated with oxidation states.

Answer (score -2):

consider any covalent compound. Say, hydrochloric acid (HCl). When we dissolve it in water, it breaks apart into H+ and Cl-. Why does a negative charge stand for an electron pair though? If you look at the bond in HCl, there is a shared pair of electrons constituting it (one from hydrogen and one from chlorine). When this bond breaks the chlorine atom takes with it the lone pair of electrons. I think this is the reason that the negative charge also represents a lone pair. As for borine, I think it acquires a pseudo-negative charge via coordinate covalent bonding with Lewis bases such as ammonia, which again, have donated a pair of electrons to it providing it with a negative charge.

Comment: BH4 does not have a "pseudo" negative charge. It has a negative charge.